# Can flutter tabs have different widths and distribute the remaining space evenly as right and left paddings?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the way i tried to do it, but i obviously need the paddings to be calculated somehow. I'm thinking in a worst case scenario creating some sort of function that calculates all that, but can i select elements and get values?

This is roughly how i want them to look like (space between should vary in accordance to screen sizes) https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLjkN.png

I'm also thinking maybe some screens might not be able to fit it since the emulated one is pretty big, in which case i'm also thinking of having a minimum padding size and just make them scrollable.

```
bottom: TabBar(
  labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
  isScrollable: true,
  tabs: <Widget>[
    Tab(
      text: 'General',
    ),
    Tab(
      text: 'Financial',
    ),
    Tab(
      text: 'Experts & Participants',
    ),
  ],
)),
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way the `TabBar` is implemented, doesn't allow to set flexible tabs. So you have to calculate the horizontal padding for each tab.

You'll need to get the tab widths, so you could do this:

- Set a `GlobalKey` to each `Tab` and then access to
  `key.currentContext.size.width`.
- Since `key.currentContext` would be `null` during build, you need to
  wait until the `TabBar` is rendered and then get the tabs width. To do
  that, you could use `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback()`
  inside `initState`.
- If the device orientation can change, you need to calculate the padding
  again, so you could do that inside `didChangeDependencies` instead of
  `initState`.
- After you calculate the padding, you need to store that padding in a
  variable and call `setState` to update the padding of the tabs.
- To avoid calling `setState` in the entire tree, you could put the
  `TabBar` in a custom `StatefulWidget`.
- To be able to do this with any `TabBar` in the app, you could create a
  custom `TabBar` widget, that receives the `TabBar` and return a new one
  with the calculated padding.

So, depending on your case, you could implement some or all of the points mentioned. Here is an example with all the points mentioned:

```
class TabBarWithFlexibleTabs extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  TabBarWithFlexibleTabs({this.child});

  final TabBar child;

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => child.preferredSize;

  @override
  _TabBarWithFlexibleTabsState createState() => _TabBarWithFlexibleTabsState();
}

class _TabBarWithFlexibleTabsState extends State<TabBarWithFlexibleTabs> {
  final _tabs = <Widget>[];
  final _tabsKeys = <Tab, GlobalKey>{};
  var _tabsPadding = 0.0;

  void _updateTabBarPadding() => setState(() {
        final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        final tabBarWidth = _tabsKeys.values
            .fold(0, (prev, tab) => prev + tab.currentContext.size.width);
        _tabsPadding = tabBarWidth < screenWidth
            ? ((screenWidth - tabBarWidth) / widget.child.tabs.length) / 2
            : widget.child.labelPadding?.horizontal ?? 16.0;
      });

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.child.tabs.forEach((tab) => _tabsKeys[tab] = GlobalKey());
    _tabs.addAll(widget.child.tabs
        .map((tab) => Container(key: _tabsKeys[tab], child: tab)));
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _updateTabBarPadding());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: widget.child.tabs.length,
      child: TabBar(
        tabs: _tabs,
        isScrollable: true,
        labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: _tabsPadding,
          vertical: widget.child.labelPadding?.vertical ?? 0,
        ),
        // TODO: pass other parameters used in the TabBar received, like this:
        controller: widget.child.controller,
        indicatorColor: widget.child.indicatorColor,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And you could use it like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBarWithFlexibleTabs(
          child: TabBar(
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(
                text: 'General',
              ),
              Tab(
                text: 'Financial',
              ),
              Tab(
                text: 'Experts & Participants',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
    ),
  );
}
```

Notes:

- The `TabBar` will be scrollable if it can't fit the screen width.
- Check the `// TODO: pass other parameters used in the TabBar received`.
- You may need to remove the `DefaultTabController` if you want to use
  a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

It is much simpler, just set the `isScrollable: true` property and it adapts automatically, this does not make it scrollable if it is not necessary